# /dev/cu port resource always busy on OS X 10.10

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, mac-os

Is there any reason why is my `/dev/cu` port always busy? How can I fix that?

It happened on both Uno clone and Spark Core.

The problem is, I'm having issues doing serial communication. Where (as a programmer) I'm seeing something like dropped packets with `/dev/tty` port. I did a quick test running it on Win 7 (a loaner PC), it works fine...

The code for now is extremely simple. It waits for a command, and write a response.

```
String str = String(30);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    str = "";
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char inChar = Serial.read();
        if ((inChar == '\n') || (inChar == '\r') || (inChar == 'z')) {
            str.trim();
            if(str == "READ") {
                String x = String(random(27, 45)) + "," + String(random(45, 300)) + "," + String(random(35, 250));
                Serial.println(x);
            }
            str = "";
        }
        else {
            if (str.length() < 30) {
                str += inChar;
            }
            else {
                str = "";
                str += inChar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I always use the `tty` one, and not the `cu` on my mac.

Comment: Yeah, me too. But so far, I've only need to upload sketches. Never really thought nor care about `tty` or `cu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I need to call [Serial.flush()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Flush).

> Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete.

Comment: Serial.flush() is not my solution. anyone with any new information on this?